# Add 1 scrollbar for 2 richtextboxes in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I want to **add a scrollbar** which can be used for both these richtextboxes in winforms so that when i scroll down, the text in these boxes goes down. Right now, both have different scrollbars. I have tried the following methods which **didn't work**:

1. Set autoscroll property to true in the tablelayoutpanel in which these richtextboxes are present.
2. Set autoscroll property to true in the normal panel in which these richtextboxes are present.

[image]

Comment: Either add a vertical scrollbar that will scroll both textboxes using [P/Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2585177/529282) or [subscribe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14163153/529282) to scrollbar event on both textboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can disable scrollbars on your RichTextBox controls and add some VScrollBar control on the right or left. 
Please reference to MSDN description of this control: [VScrollBar on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.vscrollbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like @szataniel write. For this, and scroll bar control on your form, set richTextBoxes property ScrollBar=None or SrollBar=Horizontal.

And then add code like this:

```
    private void vScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = e.NewValue;
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        richTextBox2.SelectionStart = e.NewValue;
        richTextBox2.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

Also there is another variant. You can create your own RichTextBox class extands RichTextBox with synhroniztion methods like in the post by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937123/scrolling-two-rich-text-boxes-together-i-cant-figure-it-out)